# How to fix install YOLO V8?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, yolo, yolov8

I have problem when I install YOLO V8 and run yolo checks on command line, the system report error. Please help me fix this problem.

My code :

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
resutf = model.predict("bus.jpg", save = True)
```

The error:

```
[0x7FFAB809E0A4] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Private\WORKSPACE\YOLOTEST\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    resutf = model.predict("bus.jpg", save = True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 231, in predict
    self.predictor.setup_model(model=self.model, verbose=is_cli)
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 306, in setup_model
    device=select_device(self.args.device, verbose=verbose),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\torch_utils.py", line 105, in select_device
    s += f'CPU ({get_cpu_info()})\n'
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\torch_utils.py", line 57, in get_cpu_info
    info = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()  # info dict
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cpuinfo\cpuinfo.py", line 2762, in get_cpu_info
    output = json.loads(output, object_hook = _utf_to_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MV220699\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

I use python 3.11.4